# Git-p4 submit is pushing new files from /a/b/<new files> to /a/b/a/b/<new files>

Tags: git, github, perforce, git-p4, perforce-stream

I'm probably overcomplicating things, and am probable in a unique situation here, but if anything stands out to anyone, would love some ideas.

Summary:
I am trying to copy a chunk of source code from our perforce repo to github and manually keep them in sync.  The initial setup and push to git worked great, but now things are falling apart.  For example right now another team submitted a PR with a bunch of files in /dira/dirb/

I accepted the PR, pulled the changes down to my local git project, merged them to the p4 branch, but when I tried to submit it, p4 doubled the directories - pushing all of the files from /dira/dirb to /dira/dirb/dira/dirb/

The details:

We are using streams, so the first thing I did was create a substream with just the code I was interested in. Since I don't need this substream forever (eventually the whole repo is going to git) I used a task stream:

```
    Stream Root: //streambase/taskstream
    Parent: //streambase/projectstream
    Paths:  exclude ...  (exclude the original project)
            share dira/dirb/...
            exclude dira/dirb/buildcode/...
```

Which gave me a view of:

```
    -//streambase/taskstream/... ...
    //streambase/taskstream/dira/dirb/... dira/dirb/...
    -//streambase/taskstream/dira/dirb/buildcode/... dira/dirb/buildcode/...
```

Next, created a new workspace for the substream:

```
  Workspace name: substream_workspace
  Workspace root: /Users/me/p4/gitp4parent/gitp4project
  Stream: taskstream (//streambase/taskstream)

  Workspace Mappings
      -//streambase/taskstream/... //substream_workspace/...
      //streambase/taskstream/dira/dirb/... //substream_workspace/dira/dirb/...
      -//streambase/taskstream/dira/dirb/buildcode/... //substream_workspace/dira/dirb/buildbode/...
```

- Created a .p4config file just above where I was going to clone:

```
vi /Users/me/p4/gitp4parent/.p4config
    P4USER=me
    P4CLIENT=substream_workspace
```

I then git p4 cloned the perforce substream to my local machine

```
        git p4 clone //substream/taskstream
```

My local version of git created a 'master' branch. I created a new 'main' branch, merged master to it, and gave it a remote of a repo in our github account:

```
git branch main
git checkout main
git remote add github git@github:mycompany/taskproject
git push -u github main
```

When I accepted the PR, I fetched it back into the local 'main' branch, switched to master, and merged.

At this point all of the files from the PR were under dira/dirb.
When I did `git p4 submit –prepare-p4-only`,
all of the local files were moved to dira/dirb/dira/dirb and showed up in the changelist accordingly.

Comment: Which version of git-p4 are you using?

Comment: Are the files moved on disk, or only within perforce?

Comment: My git version is git version 2.21.0 (Apple Git-122.2) (I can't find any other version for git-p4)
The files are moved on disk, which was the really surprising part

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get this to work at all. I think git-p4 just isn't up to the handling of streams. Possibly if you have sufficient permissions, https://www.perforce.com/products/helix4git might be better?

Comment: I appreciate your attempt to get it work.  I'm actually using p4 directly - I did a p4 status and p4 reconcile to get stuff checked in, and Im using p4 sync and git add when I need to push back to git. So far so good.  This aren't many changes happening here so this hybrid system seems to work well enough.  Thanks for looking at it.